# Allow an app through Windows Defender Firewall

Tags: windows-10, firewall

I have moved the new Chromium Edge to a drive other than C:\ using the robocopy command and by creating a junction. The browser is working fine as of now.

But when I launched the app after copying it to another drive and typed a website in the URL bar, the Windows Firewall popped up asking me if I want to allow access via my network or not. Since I am at my home currently, I selected only the first option and clicked "Allow access" from the menu similar to this:

[image]

So, the question that I want to ask is - Will I be able to use the internet through Chromium Edge at my university since it is a public network (and I have allowed it to access internet only through my home network through the firewall menu)? Or will I have to change the permission for this Browser in Firewall Menu to make it work there?

Comment: Just click Allow Access button.

Comment: @Wasif - Question updated.

Comment: It's still not clear what your question is.  Have you tried hitting "allow access"?

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, I have updated the question again to explain a bit more :|